# Let $H = \langle x \rangle$. Assume $\lvert x \rvert = \infty$. Then $H = \langle x^a \rangle$ iff $a = \pm 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

This is "left to the reader as an exercise" in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra. Here's my attempt;

> We need to prove two things;
>   \begin{align}
> (i)&\ \text{If $a = \pm1$ then $H = \langle x^a \rangle$};\\
> (ii)&\ \text{If $H = \langle x^a \rangle$ then $a = \pm 1$}.
> \end{align}
>   The proof of $(i)$ is immediate since if $a = \pm 1$ then $H = \langle x^{\pm 1}\rangle = \langle x\rangle$, so we proceed straight to $(ii)$. If $H = \langle x^a\rangle$ and $a = k \neq \pm 1$ then we have that that 
>   \begin{align} H &= \lbrace (x^k)^n : n \in \Bbb Z\rbrace\\
> & = \lbrace 1, x^k, x^{2k}, \ldots\rbrace. \end{align} $H$ was defined to be $H =\langle x \rangle$, while this misses out the elements $x^2,\ldots,x^{k-1}, x^{k+1}, \ldots, x^{2k-1}, \ldots$ and so $k$ must be equal to $1$.

I feel like the second part of this argument is extremely shoddy, or am I just paranoid? Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if a subgroup $H$ generated by $x$ is of infinity order, then $H=\langle x^a\rangle$ iff $a = ±1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264475/prove-that-if-a-subgroup-h-generated-by-x-is-of-infinity-order-then-h-lan)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree; the second part of the argument is ambiguous and doesn't explain why $x^2$ is missing from $H$. Here's a clearer argument:

Let $H=\langle x^a \rangle$. Since we are given $H=\langle x\rangle$, we have $x \in H$. Since $H=\langle x^a\rangle$, all $g \in H$ are in the form $x^{ak}$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$, so we get:
$$x^{ak}=x \implies x^{ak-1}=1$$
Since $x$ has infinite order, the only we this can be is if $ak-1=0$, or $ak=1$, or $a \mid 1$, or $a=\pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With the line $$x^{ak} = x \implies x^{ak-1} = 1$$ do you mean to say that there exists a $k$ such that blah blah the above stuff?

Comment: @Ed_4434 Yes, what I mean is that there exists a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^{ak}=x$. Basically, what I'm showing here is that $H$ "misses out the element" $x$ unless $a=\pm 1$.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot.