# Prove that if a subgroup $H$ generated by $x$ is of infinity order, then $H=\langle x^a\rangle$ iff $a = ±1$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

I am trying to prove a proposition in Dummit and Foote book which says:

Let $H = \langle x \rangle$. Assume $|x| = \infty$.Then $H = \langle x^a \rangle$ if and only if $=±1$.

My attempt was:
If $=±1$, then obviously $H = \langle x^{-1} \rangle = \langle x \rangle$, since for $H$ to be a group it must also contain inverses of $x$.

Conversely, if $H = \langle x^a \rangle$, we have $|x| = \infty$ hence $|H| = \infty$, which implies $|x^a| = \infty$, from here I don't know how to prove that $=±1$. I know that $x^a \neq 1$ for all non zero $a$

Comment: Hint: there exists $k$ such that $(x^a)^k = x$, since $x\in H$.

Comment: I was just in the middle of typing that as a slightly longer hint, but good enough here :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $H = \langle x \rangle$. Assume $\lvert x \rvert = \infty$. Then $H = \langle x^a \rangle$ iff $a = \pm 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992374/let-h-langle-x-rangle-assume-lvert-x-rvert-infty-then-h-langl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint: If $H = \langle x^a \rangle$, then we must have $x \in H$. Therefore, there is some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^{ak} = x$.

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Anyway that would mean $ak = 1$ and in $\mathbb{Z}$ that leaves either $a=1$ and $k=1$ or $a=-1$ and $k = -1$ which gives the result-

Comment: Or $x^{ak-1} = 1$ implies $ak-1=0$ since $\langle x^a \rangle$ is of infinity order so $a$ divides 1, which leaves $=±1$